# Testing graph bipartitness

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, bipartite

I wrote an algorithms for testing graph bipartitness for Graph Algorithms course on edX (initially available on Coursera) and it fails on one of their test cases.

I gave it a thought and cannot find so far what might I be missing, I use BFS traversal to color nodes to test for bipartitness, it works on a few simple test cases and on 17 of 28 test cases on edX.

```
private static final int WHITE = -1;
private static final int BLACK = -2;
private static final int START_INDEX = 0;

static boolean isBipartite(ArrayList<Integer>[] adj) { // an array of lists of neighbors
    int[] colors = new int[adj.length];
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[adj.length];
    colors[START_INDEX] = WHITE;
    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    // start with some node
    queue.add(START_INDEX);

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        int node = queue.poll();
        ArrayList<Integer> neighbors = adj[node];
        for (int neighbor : neighbors) {
            if (!visited[neighbor]) {
                if (node != neighbor) {
                    // add for traversal and color with an opposite color
                    queue.add(neighbor);
                    colors[neighbor] = colors[node] == WHITE ? BLACK : WHITE;
                } else {
                    // self cycle will always be odd
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                // return immediately if encountered an already colored node 
                // with the same color, there is an odd cycle
                if (colors[node] == colors[neighbor]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        visited[node] = true;
    }


    // final check of u and v colors for all edges
    for (int u = 0; u < adj.length; u++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < adj[u].size(); i++) {
            int v = adj[u].get(i);
            if (colors[u] == colors[v]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Any suggesting what could I be missing in my algorithm?
Also without the final check my algorithm would fail on the 3rd test case out of 28 (I do not see the inputs), even though I don't understand why - I should already be finding the odd cycles in the main for loop.

Please help.

Some of the sample graphs I tested myself, the 1st is not bipartite, the 2nd is bipartite.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You seem to be assuming everything is reachable from the start node.

Comment: Good point, thank you! I completely missed that.

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted in the comments, you assume that every node is reachable from the starting node. The good news is that this is quite easy to fix. Define an enum `Colors` of three values: `NoColor`, `Black`, and `White`. The pseudocode goes as follows:

Input: graph `G` with nodes integers from `0` to `n - 1`

```
Initialise array colors of length n with all values set to NoColor;
for each `i` from `0` to `n - 1`, do {
    if colors[i] = NoColor then {
        Initialise q to an empty queue (or stack - whatever floats your boat);
        push i onto queue;
        colors[i] <- Black;
        while q is not empty do {
            pop k off of q;
            for each neighbour i of k such that colors[i] = NoColor do
                colors[i] <- the opposite color of colors[k];
                push i onto q;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you the 2-coloring, if the coloring exists. In this case, you'll want to verify that it is in fact a 2-coloring to check if the graph is bipartite.